# Color and sort will not save Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am having a lot of trouble getting some of my color settings to save on the linked workbook. After I set the color and sort and save/close the workbook I lose all of that upon reopening. I have tried modifying the data source to be more static, creating an extract of the datasource, and creating both twb and twbx files without any fix. The main pages this affects are Sankey A and Step 2. Tableau hasn't been able to resolve this yet either. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[twbx file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5zfi7amot2f8kd/201604011%202Bar-SO.twbx?dl=0)

Comment: What version of Tableau Desktop are you using?

Comment: I am using 9.2 and the issue has been recreated in 9.3 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Tableau developer had to jump in and correct this workbook in the back end xml. There was a bug that was corrected for 10.x and forward.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but this may help you get in the right direction.

I tried 3 things.

1. Keep only Group Step 1 as a color dimension. This saved the color palette choice.
2. Keep only Group Step 2 as the color dimension. This did not save the color palette choice.
3. Keep Group Step 1 as a color dimension, remove Group Step 2 as a color dimension, and add Group Step 3 as a second color dimension. Color palette choice was saved.

I'm guessing there's something amiss with Group Step 2. I looked at the xml but nothing stood out. You might consider submitting a ticket to Tableau with this additional information.

Wish I could be more help.